# Runtime error: asyncio.run cannot be called from running event loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

import discord

import os

import schedule

import time

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!")

@client.event

async def on_ready():

```
print(f'{client.user} is now online!')
```

print('eho')

run = False

async def task():

```
while not client.is_closed():

    embeds = []

    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G980F Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/misc/deal-of-the-day/pcmcat248000050016.c?id=pcmcat248000050016', headers=headers)

    content = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

    wf = soup.find('div', class_='wf-wrapper')

    ofs = wf.findAll('div', class_='wf-offer')

    if ofs == None:

        return

    for of in ofs:

        title = of.find('a', class_="wf-offer-link v-line-clamp ").text

        l = of.find('a', class_='wf-offer-link')

        link = "https://bestbuy.com"+l.get('href')

        image = of.find('img', class_="wf-image img-responsive").get('src')

        p = of.find('div', class_="priceView-hero-price priceView-customer-price")

        price = p.find('span').text

        was = of.find('div', class_="pricing-price__regular-price")

        if was == None:

            was = 'NAN'

        else:

            was = was.text

        discount = of.find('div', class_="pricing-price__savings")

        if discount == None:

            discount = 'NAN'

        

        embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{title}', url=link, color=0xff9a03)

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=image)

        embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f'{title}', inline=False)

        embed.add_field(name="Price", value=f'{price}', inline=True)

        embed.add_field(name="Was", value=f'{was}', inline=True)

        embed.add_field(name="Discounted", value=f'{discount}', inline=True)

        embeds.append(embed)

    for embed in embeds:

        channel_id = '1041263119814631436';

        channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), id=channel_id)

        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    time.sleep(20)
```

async def main():

```
async with client:

    client.loop.create_task(task())

    await client.run('***')
```

asyncio.run(main())

#client.run(os.environ['token'])

`

replaced token with ***

error: title

it was meant to scrape deals of the day from bestbuy and paste it to discord every 30mins/secs

Comment: please fix the formatting

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `asyncio.run()` inside of itself. `Client.run()` already calls this, so you can't use `Client.run()` in an async main.

If you only want to log something to Discord, you don't need a Client/Bot at all. This can just be done using a simple Webhook.

Also, `Client.run()` is not async, so you can't await it...

If you really want  to use an async main and start your bot in in it, use `Client.start()` instead, which *is* async and *doesn't* call `asyncio.run()` internally. Note that this does not configure logging, so you'll have to do that yourself.